# Get Elasticsearch Version with Java API

Tags: java, api, elasticsearch

I am looking for the Java API pendant to
`curl -XGET http://localhost:9200`

With a Result like:

```
{
  "ok" : true, 
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Kierrok",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "0.90.7",
    "build_hash" : "36897d07dadcb70886db7f149e645ed3d44eb5f2",
    "build_timestamp" : "2013-11-13T12:06:54Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.5.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I expect it somewhere in the admin() part of the java api? I can't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this Solution(Scala Code but Java API)

```
case class GetEsVersionQuery(esClient: Client) {
  lazy val p = promise[NodesInfoResponse]()

  esClient
    .admin()
    .cluster()
    .prepareNodesInfo()
    .all()
    .execute()
    .addListener(new ActionListener[NodesInfoResponse] {

    def onFailure(e: Throwable) = {
      p failure e
    }

    def onResponse(response: NodesInfoResponse) = p success response
  })

  def execute: Future[NodesInfoResponse] = p.future
}

def testElasticsearchVersion: Future[Boolean] = {
    GetEsVersionQuery(esClient).execute map {
      esVersion => {
        val nodes = esVersion.iterator().toList
        nodes forall(node => node.getVersion.after(Version.V_0_90_5))
      }
    } recover {
      case e: Throwable => false
    }
  }
}
```

Credits to David Pilato from the elasticsearch usergroup.

Comment: I got error `org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Utils: fatal error on the network layer` on ElasticSearch v5 with transport client.

Answer (score 0):

There's a resource in the jar file: es-build.properties. This has most of the relevant information you need. The easiest is proably just opening that file and reading the properties.

```
version=0.90.6
hash=e2a24efdde0cb7cc1b2071ffbbd1fd874a6d8d6b
timestamp=1383573249653
```

Comment: But that is only the version of the client. What if I dont have an embedded Node but use an Transport Client to get data from an external elasticsearch cluster.

Comment: You should make the embedded node version line up with your cluster. I don't think nice things happen when they are not aligned.

Comment: Thats not really the point here. I asked for a method to get the Elasticsearch Version of the Cluster through the Java API. The pendant of the given curl command.

Your answer is not answering my problem...

Comment: Sure, I get your point. The solution you posted below seems to actually get this info for each node in the cluster so that seems to be the answer indeed.